# Distorted generated texture coordinates on extruded surface

Tags: texturing

I have an extruded surface, but its generated texture coordinates are distorted as shown. If I choose UV coordinates, the mapping is correct. However, what do I need to reset so that the generated coordinates will work as usual?

[image]

Comment: Generated texture coordinates are probably projecting from the wrong direction, you have to adjust them using a *Vector Mapping Node*

Comment: As you show plane with a texture shown in viewport and want to use Generated texture coordinates, I suppose you use Blender Internal. In this case, texture coordinates can be adjusted in Mapping rollout in texture settings . I can also assume that your plane is rotated along Y axis.